# Django queryset filter for most recent in the past and all in the future

Tags: python, django

#### Context

I have the models `ContentBuild` & `ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink` like this:

```
# models.py

class ContentBuild(models.Model):
    content_build_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)


class ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    content_build_uuid = models.ForeignKey(ContentBuild, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='content_build_deploy')
    group_uuid = models.ForeignKey(DeviceGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    preload_date = UnixDateTimeField()
    release_date = UnixDateTimeField()
```

#### Goal

I want to return the most recent `ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink`object with the `release_date` in the past, along with all `ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink` objects with the `release_date` in the future.

#### What I tried

I tried to use the `Q object` like this:

```
in_future = Q(release_date__gte=timezone.now())
recent_past = Q(release_date__lt=timezone.now()).order_by('-release_date')[0]

ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink.objects
.filter(in_future & recent_past)
```

This does not work and throws the error:

```
'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

How do I filter for the object with `release_date` in the most recent past AND all objects with `release_date` in the future?

#### EDIT

I changed my approach so I first get the object with the most recent past and then filter all objects greater than or equal to this date. However, the queryset below works fine when there is only 1 `ContentBuild` but returns all older objects when there are more than 1 related `ContentBuild`.

```
recent_past = ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink.objects
    .filter(release_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('release_date').first()

ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink.objects.filter(release_date__gt=recent_past.release_date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt was close, but has two problems:

1. since you're plucking the `first` object off the ordered list, that's the guy with the *oldest* `release_date`, not the *most recent*
2. using `gt` instead of `gte` seems a little suspect... I'm surprised it picked anything up when there was only one `ContentBuild`

To get it in a single db query, you have a couple of options depending on your django version.  If you're running with django >= 2.0, you should be able to do it like this (I don't have a project I can test this on right now):

```
from django.db.models import Max, Q, F

ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink.objects.annotate(
    start_date=Max('release_date', filter=Q(release_date__lt=timezone.now())
).filter(release_date__gte=F('start_date'))
```

If you are running with django < 2.0, try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, F

recent_dates = ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink.objects.filter(
    release_date__lte=timezone.now()
).order_by('-release_date').values('release_date')

ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink.objects.annotate(
    start_time=Subquery(recent_dates[:1])
).filter(release_date__gte=F('start_time'))
```

There's probably a smarter way, but that seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am running Django 2.2. Your first sollution threw `Q object not callable` as an error. Your second sollution works like a charm!

Comment: That's weird.  Wish I had a 2.2 project I could try it on.  Anyway, glad the other guy worked.

Answer (score 2):

You use `order_by` not with a queryset. Try this.

```
in_future = Q(release_date__gte=timezone.now())
recent_past = Q(release_date__lt=timezone.now())

ContentBuildDeviceGroupLink.objects.filter(
    in_future & recent_past
).order_by('-release_date').first()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This results in an empty queryset. Probably because `recent_past` has all objects in the past.